# bootstrap 3 glyphicons show text on hover

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

in my html I got Bootstrap glyphicons with the following code:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-copy" style="cursor:pointer;font-size:20px;">
</span>
```

is it possible to show some text on hover on it as it is done with `img` tag. Tried to add `alt` attribute but it did not work. Maybe there are some polifills for this (tooltips) or smth like that? Bootstrap-3 is used.

Thank you.

Comment: title attribute

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rnekcsbL/ check this link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add tooltip use:

**HTML**

```
    <span 
        class="glyphicon glyphicon-copy"
        data-toggle="tooltip"
        style="cursor:pointer;font-size:20px;"
        title="myText"
    ></span>
```

**JS**

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
        });
    </script>
```

or else you can just add `data-title` attribute to your `<span>` element

```
    <span
        class="glyphicon glyphicon-copy"
        data-toggle="tooltip"
        data-title="myText"
        style="cursor:pointer;font-size:20px;"
    ></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-copy" title="yourtext" style="cursor:pointer;font-size:20px;">
```

> Add attribute **title** with *text thant you want to show on hover* .

Comment: Please motivate your answer, code is not enough to get the gist of it